# Data analysis to extract period

Tags: python

[image]

I'm only asking this question because I've recently stumbled upon some clever code that I would have never thought of on my own. The code I refer to uses the numpy python library. It coverts the signal to true/false array based on if the signal is above a threshold. Then it generates an array that aligns with the middle of each bit. Then it reshapes the data into groups of 8. It takes a half dozen lines of code to analyze thousands of points of data. I've written code that does similar things but it walks through the entire dataset using for loops looking for edges and then converts those edges to bits. It takes literally hundreds of lines of code to do.

Pictured is an example of a dataset I'm trying to analyze. The beginning always has a preamble of 8 bits that are the same. I want to extract what the period of the signal is using the preamble.

Are there any methods for doing so in python without painstakingly looking for edges?

Comment: What's your source data? A 1D or 2D array? In generally you can do edge detection with something like np.abs(x[:-1] - x[1:]) > limit

Comment: @CookieOfFortune The data is a 1D array of a million points or so. The sampling rate is known. I'm looking for how many elements are between edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Find the transitions
edges = np.abs(x[:-1] - x[1:]) > limit 

# Find the indices where the transitions occur
indices = np.where(edges)[0]

# Count the elements as the difference between the indices
counts = indices[1:] - indices[:-1]
```